# The font package tgheros affects lmodern

Tags: bold, italic, sans-serif, lmodern

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgheros}
%\usepackage{helvet}   % see explanation
\begin{document}
 Let's test \textbf{bold face text} and \textit{italics text}, and most 
 importantly 
 \textit{\textbf{italic bold}} and \textbf{\textit{bold italic}}
 
 \textsf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.} 
\end{document}
```

When this is processed, either by latex, pdflatex or lualatex, there will be a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmr/b/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmr/b/sl' tried instead on input line 9.
```

and the output that should be bold italic is in fact bold slanted, just as the warning says.

However, if helvet is used instead of tgheros, then everything works, and we get bold italics as expected.

The \textsf line is really not necessary, the error is there just if tgheros is loaded.

The TeX version is TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021), Fedora 35, separate texlive installation.

So where is the question in this? I guess the question is "to whom should such a bug report be sent?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tgheros redefines `\bfdefault`, something it better shouldn't do in a current LaTeX. You can reinstate the default definition:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bfdefault{b\@empty}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{helvet}   % see explanation
\begin{document}
 Let's test \textbf{bold face text} and \textit{italics text}, and most
 importantly
 \textit{\textbf{italic bold}} and \textbf{\textit{bold italic}}

 \textsf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\end{document}
```